# Autoset textbox values with jQuery

Tags: jquery, textbox, onkeyup

I have the following code:

```
this.urlSet = function(){
    $("#url").keyup(function(){
        $("#firstpath").val() = $("#url").val().substring(0,8);
        $("#secndpath").val() = $("#url").val().substring(0,8);
        $("#thirdpath").val() = $("#url").val().substring(0,8);
    });
};
```

I'm trying to get the three textboxes named "xxxpath" to fill with the first 8 characters of the url textbox as the user is typing. However, with the code in this state, nothing happens. Anyone have a quick idea where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `val(value_to_set)` function, because `val()` it's only to get the value:

```
this.urlSet = function(){
    $("#url").keyup(function(){
        $("#firstpath").val($("#url").val().substring(0,8));
        $("#secndpath").val($("#url").val().substring(0,8));
        $("#thirdpath").val($("#url").val().substring(0,8));
    });
};
```

Comment: Hmm I tried that as well first but it didn't work. Now it does! Must have stuck something random in there. Thanks :)